# How can I build a condition based query in Laravel 6.x?

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function test(Request $request){
    $apartments = DB::table('apartments');
    if ($request->filled('bathrooms')) {
        $apartments->where('bathrooms', '=' ,$request->input('bathrooms'));
    }
    if ($request->filled('rooms_number')) {
        $apartments->where('rooms_number', '=', $request->input('rooms_number'));
    }
    $apartments->get();
    return view('pages.test2' , compact('apartments'));
}
```

How can this code be translated so that it works in Laravel?

Comment: This query is working correct ? what you expect using eloquent ? can you clarify ?

Comment: it doesn't return the results when i divide DB::table('table') from the rest query

Comment: Its better to use DB::table('apartments')->where('bathrooms/rooms_number','=',$request->batgrooms/rooms_number)->get() in your if clauses and remove lines 2,9 .but if you dont like clean code,i think your code will work but not clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `when` as a [conditional clause](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#conditional-clauses):

```php
public function test (Request $request)
{
    $apartments = DB::table('apartments')
        ->when($request->filled('bathrooms'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->where('bathrooms', '=', $request->input('bathrooms'));
        })
        ->when($request->filled('rooms_number'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->where('rooms_number', '=', $request->input('rooms_number'));
        })
        ->get();

    return view('pages.test2' , compact('apartments'));
}
```